# I can't access to Hadoop Web Interface (DataNode, ResourceManager)

Tags: hadoop

I've installed Hadoop 3.1.1 with **pseudo-distributed mode**. I tried to access Hadoop Web Interface, and NameNode(`Server's public IP:9870`) and JobHistoryServer(`public IP:19888`) UI are opened well but DataNode(`public IP:9864`), ResourceManager(`public IP:8088`) UI are blocked.

However, when I put the command `jps`, DataNode and ResourceManager is still working. Also, there was nothing special error message in log file.

[image]

I want to know what is the problem.

**masters:**

```
localhost
```

**slaves:**

```
localhost
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>(Hadoop Home Dir)/hdata/dfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>(Hadoop Home Dir)/hdata/dfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>localhost:9864</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>(Hadoop Home Dir)/hdata</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.web-proxy.address</name>
    <value>localhost:8089</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**ResourceManager logs:**

```
2018-09-23 17:09:07,192 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting ResourceManager
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ubuntu-1cpu-40gb_ssd-2gb_ram-2tb_bw/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 3.1.1
```

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani It's Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Could you share us resourceManager logs?

Comment: You also can try adding the property `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address` with the value `localhost:8088` to the `yarn-site.xml` file and remove the property `yarn.web-proxy.address`.

Comment: If any value is `localhost` in the XML, you're not using pseudodistributed mode. It needs to be the value of `hostname -f` instead. Similarly with all slave and master files. Plus, `(Hadoop Home Dir)` should be a real file path

Comment: @cricket_007 Should I change the value of `workers` file too?

Comment: @cricket_007 I've changed all `localhost` to value of `hostname -f` and now it doesn't even start.

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani I added `resourcemanager` logs. I can't find any error messages.

Comment: Go to your `/etc/hosts` file and remove the lines with `127.0.1.1`

Comment: @cricket_007 On the server? or local pc?

Comment: On the Hadoop server(s)

Comment: Basically, by setting localhost, all services will only be available to that server, not remotely from "your local pc". And if you're running Hadoop in the cloud or some other remote server, you'll actually need to use the external IP or DNS address rather than the hostname

Comment: I changed all `localhost` values of xml files(+masters, slaves, workers) to cloud server's external IP and modified `/etc/hosts`. Now `NameNode`, `DataNode`, `ResourceManager` don't start. Umm...I didn't realize just launching Hadoop would be so difficult like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified config files like following, and now 6 processes and web interface are working well.

**/etc/hosts (Local PC/WSL)**

```
127.0.0.1                localhost
(Server's external IP)   (Server's hostname)
```

127.0.1.1 is need to be deleted.

**masters:**

```
(Server's external IP)
```

**slaves:**

```
(Server's external IP)
```

**workers:**

```
(Server's external IP)
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>(Hadoop Home Dir)/hdata/dfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>(Hadoop Home Dir)/hdata/dfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>(Hadoop Home Dir)/hdata</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You still have localhost in the XML, though. Might be the issue. You can use the internal IP for the datanodes, but the web services need to use external addresses

Comment: @cricket_007 No, If I change it, `NameNode` doesn't start. So I left localhost on `core-site.xml`.

Comment: But you're going to get 0 datanodes if you don't change it to something else, so it will have to be a different value at some point

Comment: @cricket_007 I just formatted Hadoop data directory and one live `DataNode` has appeared. But its HTTP address is `(Server hostname):9864` so `Connection Refused` error is occurred. Can I force `DataNode` to access to web ui with IP instead of hostname? It works well if I access through server's external IP address.

Comment: Yeah, IP are actually preferred until you can get DNS working successfully. You can always edit the /etc/hosts file to statically set the IP to a host

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I set `(Server's external IP)   (Server's hostname)` on the server's `/etc/hosts` file but still I can't access to web ui with hostname.

Comment: You need to set that on your local pc, not the server

Comment: Finally I found the problem. I forgot that I was using WSL, not native Linux. I've modified both `/etc/hosts` of Windows and WSL so now I can access to web interface through server's hostname.